# How solve nonlinear equations by 14 unknowns?

Tags: equation-solving

This is my code, i want to solve system by 14 equations and 14 unknowns(rr list).But the code doesn't run...

```
Clear["Global`*"]
T[0, t_] = 1;
T[1, t_] = t;
T[n_, t_] := 2 *t*T[n - 1, t] - T[n - 2, t];
For[n = 0, n <= 7, n++, Print["T[", n, ",t]= ", T[n, t], "\n"]];
tableoft = tt /.NSolve[T[7, tt], tt];
tableoft[[1]];
Subscript[z, 1][t_] = Sum[Simplify[Subscript[a, j]*T[j, t]], {j, 0, 6}];
Subscript[z, 2][t_] = Sum[Simplify[Subscript[b, l]*T[l, t]], {l, 0, 6}];
f[t_] = (t^4/6 - t^3/3 + t) /. t -> 1/2*(τ + 1);
Subscript[k, 1][t_, s_] = s^3 /. s -> 1/4*(τ + 1)*(r + 1);
Subscript[k, 1][t, s]*Subscript[z, 1][r];
p[τ_] = 
 Integrate[Subscript[k, 1][t, s]*Subscript[z, 1][r], {r, -1, 1}]
Subscript[k, 2][t_, s_] = -2 (t - s) /. t -> 1/2*(τ + 1) /. 
  s -> 1/4*(τ + 1)*(r + 1);
Subscript[k, 2][t, s]*Subscript[z, 2][r];
    pp[τ_] = 
 Integrate[Subscript[k, 2][t, s]*Subscript[z, 2][r], {r, -1, 1}];
Subscript[g, 2][τ_] = 
 Expand[(f[t] + p[τ] + pp[τ])^2] // N;
Subscript[δ, 
  1][τ_] = ((Subscript[z, 
    1][τ])*((f[t] + p[τ] + pp[τ])) - 1) // N;
Subscript[δ, 
  2][τ_] = (Subscript[z, 2][τ] -Subscript[g, 2][τ]) // N;
 Table[N[Subscript[δ, 1][tableoft[[i]]]], {i, 1, 7}];
 Table[N[Subscript[δ, 2][tableoft[[i]]]], {i, 1, 7}];
 r = Flatten[Table[N[{Subscript[δ, 1][tableoft[[i]]], 
 Subscript[δ, 2][tableoft[[i]]]}], {i, 1, 7}]];
 rr =Table[Simplify[r[[i]]] == 0, {i, 1, 14}]
 list =Flatten[Table[{Subscript[a, i], Subscript[b, i]}, {i, 0, 6}]];
 Solve[rr, list]
```

How to get solution fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `FindRoot` like so:

```
sol = FindRoot[rr, Thread[{list, ConstantArray[0, Length[list]]}]]

(* {Subscript[a, 0] -> 18.9824, Subscript[b, 0] -> 0.43251, 
 Subscript[a, 1] -> -33.3436, Subscript[b, 1] -> 0.65013, 
 Subscript[a, 2] -> 27.5785, Subscript[b, 2] -> 0.279464, 
 Subscript[a, 3] -> -22.0304, Subscript[b, 3] -> 0.0771869, 
 Subscript[a, 4] -> 16.5283, Subscript[b, 4] -> 0.0177385, 
 Subscript[a, 5] -> -11.0201, Subscript[b, 5] -> 0.00270039, 
 Subscript[a, 6] -> 5.51, Subscript[b, 6] -> 0.000329395} *)
```

Another way is to remove the `Solve` and instead do a minimization. Transform the equations `lhs == rhs` into `lhs - rhs == 0` if they aren't like this already, then minimize the total square error from zero:

```
{err, sol} = NMinimize[Total[(rr /. Equal -> Subtract)^2], list]

(* {1.00027*10^-26, {Subscript[a, 0] -> 18.9824, 
  Subscript[b, 0] -> 0.43251, Subscript[a, 1] -> -33.3436, 
  Subscript[b, 1] -> 0.65013, Subscript[a, 2] -> 27.5785, 
  Subscript[b, 2] -> 0.279464, Subscript[a, 3] -> -22.0304, 
  Subscript[b, 3] -> 0.0771869, Subscript[a, 4] -> 16.5283, 
  Subscript[b, 4] -> 0.0177385, Subscript[a, 5] -> -11.0201, 
  Subscript[b, 5] -> 0.00270039, Subscript[a, 6] -> 5.51, 
  Subscript[b, 6] -> 0.000329395}} *)

rr[[All, 1]] /. sol

(* {0., -3.46945*10^-18, 2.22045*10^-16, -2.34188*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-15,
  5.55112*10^-17, -1.66533*10^-15, 1.77636*10^-15, -4.32987*10^-15, 
 3.55271*10^-15, -1.9984*10^-15, 0., -5.88418*10^-15, -8.52651*10^-14} *)
```

As you can see, substituting these values satisfies all equations at an error under 10^-13.